# Install Python bindings for LimeReport on windows

Tags: python, windows, pip

Install [LimeReport-qt-6-4 1.7.6](https://pypi.org/project/LimeReport-qt-6-4/) a Python bindings for [LimeReport](https://github.com/fralx/LimeReport) on windows

I tried to install it on ubuntu 23.10 using `pip install LimeReport-qt-6-4` and it worked - python 3.11 and PySide6 6.6.2

I'm trying to install it on windows but it stops with `Installing build dependencies ... error`.
I tried with different versions of python (3.9, 3.11, 3.12) and PySide6 (6.4.2 and 6.6.2) but still doesn't work.

Any suggestions how to install it on windows?

This is the full error message I got:

```
Collecting LimeReport-qt-6-4
  Using cached LimeReport-qt-6-4-1.7.6.tar.gz (15.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      Collecting cmake>=3.18
        Using cached cmake-3.28.3-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (6.5 kB)
      Collecting setuptools>=42
        Using cached setuptools-69.1.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.2 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
      ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 6.3.0 Requires-Python <3.11,>=3.6; 6.3.1 Requires-Python <3.11,>=3.6; 6.3.2 Requires-Python <3.11,>=3.6; 6.4.0 Requires-Python <3.11,>=3.6; 6.4.0.1 Requires-Python <3.12,>=3.7; 6.4.1 Requires-Python <3.12,>=3.7; 6.4.2 Requires-Python <3.12,>=3.7; 6.4.3 Requires-Python <3.12,>=3.7; 6.5.0 Requires-Python <3.12,>=3.7; 6.5.1 Requires-Python <3.12,>=3.7; 6.5.1.1 Requires-Python <3.12,>=3.7; 6.5.2 Requires-Python <3.12,>=3.7; 6.5.3 Requires-Python <3.12,>=3.7
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement shiboken6==6.4.2 (from versions: 6.6.0, 6.6.1, 6.6.2)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for shiboken6==6.4.2
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: Can you post your full errro message and traceback?

Comment: I updated the post with the error message

Comment: It cannot find `shiboken6`, on Pypi, it looks like that only has whl files for python 3.8, so you could try that python version

Answer (score 0):

## I tried to install it for myself:

[image]
***It's also stuck, just like yours***

Try to contact the author Maxim Slipenko (python-limereport@maks1ms.anonaddy.com)

**OR**

*Break down the boundaries between Windows and Linux, use:*

[WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/) (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

**OR**

*Use the Docker container to avoid thinking about the operating system.*

***Good luck!***

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. But can I deploy my application to run on windows at the user side?

Comment: This is a little different from what you asked about.
Use a Docker container to avoid thinking about the OS on the client side.

Comment: Did you manage to use LimeReport in Windows?

Comment: not yet. Actually I'm not a programmer. Just interested in learning in my free time.